# Another term for ' having sex with non-living things'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single term for who have sex with non-living things?

Comment: It wouldn't be called *having sex* if one is *getting off* on objects. Unless you mean *non-living* as in *dead people or animals*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

People who derive sexual satisfaction from inanimate objects are referred to as objectum sexuals.

http://www.objectum-sexuality.org/

Comment: That may not be a suitable language reference -- is that term defined in any dictionaries/ standard references?

Comment: Please don't objectophile me!

Answer (score 3):

*Paraphilia* is the common term for all abnormal love, including that with inanimate objects. The Greek suffix -phile is also used to describe someone having sex with an object (i.e. zoophile = someone who has sex with animals). So you could describe someone having sex with non-living things as a *paraphile*.

Comment: Although possibly confusing them with people who like members of an airborne regiment

Answer (score 3):

I think the word is just [masturbation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masturbation) *- a common form of autoeroticism, providing sexual pleasure or orgasm in the absence of a partner.*

Wikipedia defines even a [blow-up sex doll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_doll) as *aid in masturbation*, so unless by "non-living" OP means "dead" (in which case it's [necrophilia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necrophilia)), anything inanimate involved in "solo sex" is a masturbatory aid and/or the [object of a fetish](http://health.howstuffworks.com/sexual-health/sexuality/fetishism-dictionary.htm).